# Как реализовать систему поощрений пользователя на php (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, логика

Как реализовать подобную систему? То есть например награда за первый вход в систему, за 10 комментариев или же за ежедневный заход на сайт. То есть понятно как хранить эти поощрения, это банально, но как отслеживать выполнение их условий и выполнять их логику?

Comment: Так-то способов хватает.. От ивентов до крона или же просто проверки в коде

Comment: Ну то есть на каждую награду реализовывать какой то метод, какие то нужно пихать в крон, какие то нужно вызывать ивентами - это ж каша какая то получится, красивым решением было бы хранить логику прям в записи каждого поощрения - типо скрипта, который сервис бы перегонял в логику.

Comment: Всё одним скриптов не сделать. Тут главное составить конкретный список всех возможных поощрений - потом видно будет как лучше реализовать

Comment: Вот и спрашиваю, может у кого то был опыт, надо еще определиться от чего "танцевать", ну например брать пользователя и проверять все возможные награды или же брать награды и прогонять её по всем пользователям... Вообще сообразить не могу